# Producing NAN when i need the total

Tags: javascript, nan

The program needs to generate a random number for the `presentValue`, `months`, and  `interest` rate between .1-.10%.

When performing the final calculation I get NaN.

```
var count = 5;

function futureValue(presentValue, interest, months) {
  var step1 = 1 + Number(interest);
  var step2 = parseFloat(Math.pow(step1, months));
  var step3 = presentValue * step2;
  return "The future value is: " + step3;
}

for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  var presentValue = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  var interest = ((Math.random() * .10 - 0.1) + .1).toFixed(2)
  var months = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
  futureValue(presentValue, interest, months)
  console.log("The present value is: " + presentValue);
  console.log("The interest rate is: " + interest);
  console.log("The number of months is: " + months);
  console.log(futureValue());
}
```

Comment: you are calling futureValue() with no parameters. NaN = Not a Number because you are making calculations with "undefined" which indeed, is Not a Number,

Comment: Unrelated, but please indent your code and use consistent whitespace rules--makes things much easier to read and think about. Also, why call the function twice?

Comment: Also note:  .1 and .10 are the same number... (percentage or not)  This seems to give an interest rate from 0 to .1 (ie: 0% to 10%)

Answer (score 5):

You need to pass in the arguments:

```
console.log(futureValue())
```

to

```
console.log(futureValue(presentValue,interest,months))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are calling futureValue() with no parameters. It returns NaN (Not a Number) because you are making calculations with "undefined" which indeed, is Not a Number,

Try:

```js
var count = 5
function futureValue(presentValue,interest,months){
var step1 = 1 + Number(interest);
var step2 = parseFloat(Math.pow(step1,months));
var step3 = presentValue*step2;
return("The future value is: " + step3);


}


for (i=0;i<count;i++){
var presentValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
var interest = ((Math.random()*.10-0.1)+.1).toFixed(2)
var months = Math.floor(Math.random()*100)
var fv = futureValue(presentValue,interest,months) //save your futureValue in a variable.
console.log("The present value is: " + presentValue);
console.log("The interest rate is: " + interest);
console.log("The number of months is: " + months);
console.log(fv)//log your calculated future value

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line calculates the future value correctly, and does nothing with it.

```
futureValue(presentValue,interest,months);
```

This line returns calls the `futureValue` function with no parameters, which returns `NaN` and writes the result to the log.

```
console.log(futureValue());
```

What you should do is assign the value to a variable, and then log that value:

```
var futureVal = futureValue(presentValue,interest,months);
console.log(futureVal);
```

Or just:

```
console.log(futureValue(presentValue,interest,months));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because

```
return("The future value is: " + step3);
```

Is a string.  So, it indeed, is not a number.

You should return JUST the number, then create the string.

Answer (score 0):

Once you call `futureValue(presentValue,interest,months)` the value disappears. If you want to console.log the result you should store it in a variable and then console.log that.